# Python Requests POST to PHP

Tags: php, python

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

I'm having trouble sending a post request to a web form, [GO Term](http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/Program/GOCompareTwo1.php), that asks for two GO (gene ontology) terms. From what I can see, this form posts to another php file, [GO Compare](http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/Program/GOCompareTwo2.php), which sends back the numeric similarity of these two terms via http.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
url = 'http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/Program/GOCompareTwo1.php'
GOterms = {'GOTerm1':'0005777','GOTerm2':'0005739'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)`
```

All this returns is the webpage of GO Term. Substituting the url for **GO Compare** returns a web page with the status code 500, and no similarity value. I am very new to HTTP requests, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Am I misunderstanding the source code of both web pages? Or do I have a misunderstanding about HTTP requests? Thanks again.

Edit : I realized I was not clear about what I'm trying to do. Essentially, I'm trying to send two GO terms to  G-SESAME, the website, and get back the numeric similarity of these two terms.

Comment: `http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/Program/GOCompareTwo2.php` is the url that actually receiving the request.  In chrome, you can open the developer tools and go to the network tab to see the details.

Comment: @zjk but you cant make a direct request, try it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = 'http://bioinformatics.clemson.edu/G-SESAME/Program/GOCompareTwo2.php'
GOterms = {'GOTerm1':'0005777','GOTerm2':'0005739', 'submit':'Submit'}
r = requests.post(url, data=GOterms)
print r.text
```

You can try to mimic the browser request by inspecting the info in the network tab of the developer tools

Comment: I was trying for a long time, but failed and your hint with the dev tools in the browser saved me. Turns out the data must also contain the button, just as you did it with the `'submit':'Submit'` part. Cheers