# Python Request POST to PHP

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to submit a form to automate the process of downloading archived data from [FIRMS](https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/create.php). I've tried inspecting what is being posted using the developer tools as suggested in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736940/python-requests-post-to-php), and the only thing I see being posted is "email" and "cst" (I have no idea what 'cst' is, and it changes each time I refresh the page). 
Although I can see the names of the other elements, adding them to the POST request does nothing.

```
data = {
        "region": "custom",
        "coord": [llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat],
        "source": "MODIS C6",
        "fromDate": startDate,
        "toDate": endDate,
        "output_format": "csv",
        "email": "some_email@gmail.com",
        }

# submit the request
response = requests.post(
        'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/create.php', 
        data=data)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The site uses AJAX to send those parameters to `download_save.php`, not `create.php`.

Comment: Then it redirects to `list.php`, which contains the list of files that can be downloaded.

Comment: You need to save the cookies from the first page so that the list page will show you the correct list.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @Barmar! I'm very new to this. Could you elaborate a bit more on this process, or a provide code example? Does this mean I should be sending the POST request to https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/download_save.php instead of https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/create.php ?

Comment: That's just the beginning of it. You need to emulate everything that the browser does: save cookies, go to the `list.php` page (with the cookies), find the download link there, then download that file (you'll need the cookies for that, too). It also may take some time for the download to be ready. This is a significant coding project, which will involve some web scraping.

Comment: Once I submit the form, and the files are processed, I am also emailed a link with the file to download. I've already set up a script to download the needed files from email. So, it's just the initial POST where I'm stuck. I'll try changing the url though, thanks!

Comment: In that case I think just changing the URL should be enough.

Comment: There's a checkbox in the form indicating whether you want that email. Make sure you send the corresponding parameter in your data.

Comment: Thanks, first attempt at just changing the url was not successful. I'll try again tomorrow when I'm not so tired, as there's a chance I am still missing something.  
``` data = {
     "region": "custom",
     "coord": [llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat],
     "source": "MODIS C6",
     "fromDate": startDate,
     "toDate": endDate,
     "output_format": output_format,
     "email": "some_email@gmail.com",
     "confirm_email": "checked",
     "btn_create": "SaveDownload();"
  }```
Can I ask @Barmar, where can I see the redirect to `download_save.php` for future reference?

Comment: I saw it in the Network tab. Make sure you check the "Preserve log" checkbox, otherwise the redirect to `list.php` clears out all the network operations from the first page.